# Using react-css-modules/css-modules with props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have a re-usable component called ColorInput.

However, each input has a different text color. Therefore, I have setup different classes for each input. For instance, input-red, input-green, input-blue.

**SCSS**

```
.input-red{
  composes: input;
  composes: theme-red from "./_theme-colors.scss";
}
```

**ColorInput Component**

```
class ColorInput extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return( 
      <input styleName={this.props.styleName} />
  )
}
```

}

StyleName is not outputting to proper Class.

```
<ColorInput styleName ='input-red'>
<ColorInput styleName ='input-green'>
<ColorInput styleName ='input-blue'>
```

I know that this may be a reported [issue](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules/issues/58), however, I am not sure if I have the same issue.

*Update:  I plan on including a live demo as soon as possible.*

Comment: The provided code is not enough to determine if you are doing anything wrong. Include the code that is used to decorate `ColorInput` using `react-css-modules`.